# JAR File not getting loaded in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

`servlet-api.jar` I shifted this jar file from one system to the other.

But I get the following error like `-jar not loaded. Offending class:javax/servlet/servlet.class` when I start the tomcat server.

Kindly let me know what would be the cause for this error and how to resolve the same.

Tomcat version is 5.5 in the current system and my previous system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution is that you might have another jar (like `servlet.jar`) available in a WAR file under tomcat that conflicts with `servlet-api.jar`'s `Servlet.class`.

Try and find out which WAR contains the jar and remove it.

For more, view an article [here](http://simplysimple.info/tomcat-error-jar-not-loaded-servlet-spec-23-section-972-offending-class-javaxservletservletclass/).

Comment: Indeed. To the point: you should never copy/move servletcontainer specific libraries out of their original location. Keep them where they belongs. If you did this in order to fix compilation errors (javax.servlet not found etc), then this was the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like servlet.class has dependancies that are not being met - probably in another .jar file.